# Django renders a template that does not exist in specified directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.1

I have model 'Video' and I have a list view for this model, then in another app I'm trying to create a view 'UserVideosListView' that is viewable to the dedicated user. when I open the page in the browser before making any templates for this view I'm able to see current user's videos (not all videos).

```
# inside 'users' app
class UserVideosListView(ListView):
    model = Video
    template_name = "users/user_videos.html"
    context_object_name = 'videos'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['videos'] = Video.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return context
```

---

```
# inside 'videos' app
class VideoListView(ListView):
    model = Video
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = 'videos/video_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'videos'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['videos'] = Video.published_videos.all()
        return context
```

P.S. I'm sure that the URL I'm entering is current, and there is no template inside the 'users' directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django renders **videos/video_list.html** because `ListView` is based on `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` and  `BaseListView`:

> ```
> class ListView(MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseListView):
>     """
>     Render some list of objects, set by `self.model` or `self.queryset`.
>     `self.queryset` can actually be any iterable of items, not just a queryset.
>     """
> ```

Within [**`MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/90916f050c64b817fdf2ea13b5c20986005fd029/django/views/generic/list.py#L161) ([GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/90916f050c64b817fdf2ea13b5c20986005fd029/django/views/generic/list.py#L161)), the template name is also generated based on the **model**.

> ```
> # If the list is a queryset, we'll invent a template name based on the
> # app and model name. This name gets put at the end of the template
> # name list so that user-supplied names override the automatically-
> # generated ones.
> if hasattr(self.object_list, 'model'):
>     opts = self.object_list.model._meta
>     names.append("%s/%s%s.html" % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name, self.template_name_suffix))
> ```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#multipleobjecttemplateresponsemixin) says [`MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#multipleobjecttemplateresponsemixin):

> **template_name_suffix**
>
> The suffix to append to the auto-generated candidate template name. Default suffix is **_list**.

> [**get_template_names()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names)
>
> Returns a list of candidate template names. Returns the following list:
>
> - **the value of template_name on the view (if provided)**
> - **<app_label>/<model_name><template_name_suffix>.html**

---

I suggest you to override `get_queryset()` method instead of `get_context_data()`

```
class UserVideosListView(ListView):
    model = Video
    context_object_name = 'videos'
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user))
```

Comment: Don't we use 'template_name' to ignore this?

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh, Yes, that's right, but the template should exist (found).

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Create a page for user to view their videos in dashboard

Comment: Thanks. you were right. it was because it didn't found anything in that directory

Comment: Happy to help)).